# How to limit for each loop to read multiple string with quotation as a single string in python?

Tags: python, list, csv, foreach, reader

CSV file contains below data,

> "1111"","2222"2222","3333, 33, 33","444",""

csv reader reading this data as,

> ['"1111""', '"2222"2222"', '"3333', ' 33', ' 33"', '"444"', '""']

And when I am trying to convert this reader object into list and trying to iterate this using for each loop, loop is considering "3333, 33, 33" as a three different values. My requirement is to read it as a single string.

**Code:**

```
reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=',',  quotechar="'", escapechar = "'")
       for row in reader:
           colValues = list(row)
           print(colValues)
           for each in colValues:
               print(each)
```

**Current output:**

```
"1111""
"2222"2222"
"3333
 33
 33"
"444"
""
```

**Desired Output:**

```
"1111""
"2222"2222"
"3333, 33, 33"
"444"
""
```

Comment: The file looks like the `quotechar` should be double quotes.

Comment: the `quotechar` should be double quotes as @schwobaseggl suggest, but even this will not solve the problem as file is not well formed. There is an issue that there is unescaped double quote in `"1111""` and inside `2222"2222` . Where does this file comes from?

Comment: Are the (number of) quotes important? Otherwise you could do `df = pd.read_csv(csv_file, sep='","', header=None, engine='python')`. This will give you the output: `"1111";  2222"2222 ; 3333, 33, 33;  444;  "` (';' being the separation of values in this example)

Comment: @buran - we get this file from third party so we don't have any control on this. It  may contain double quote in string value too. I am creating a utility to make fix it in correct format.

Comment: would it be easier if you just split it with `string.split(",\"")` and then do a list comprehension `[i if i.startswith("\"") else "\""+i for i in result]`?

Comment: I wonder whether it would be better to specify the format rather than try to interpret it as csv. It doesn't seem regular enough to be able to shoehorn it in.

Comment: Henry - This is not working. Any other workaround? by customizing for each loop or any other method so that I can parse it while reading in loop?

Comment: Can you confirm that the actual file is poorly formatted, i.e. this looks like dummy data just for the SO question? Potentially one may try to use regex, but it's not clear if it will work, Another alternative is to try some workaround, e.g. split at `","` and try to process the resulting list one way or another.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think the `csv` module can handle this irregular format.

You could split based upon `","` which would get you the correct columns. You would also need to strip the first and last quote.

```
>>> row = '"1111"","2222"2222","3333, 33, 33","444",""'
>>> row = row[1:-1]
>>> print(row)
1111"","2222"2222","3333, 33, 33","444","

>>> row.split('","')
['1111"', '2222"2222', '3333, 33, 33', '444', '']
```

Altogether:

```
with open(csv_file) as lines:
    for line in lines:
        line = line.rstrip()  # need to get rid of newline
        for element in line[1:-1].split('","'):
            print(element)
```

Output:

```
1111"
2222"2222
3333, 33, 33
444
```

Comment: Thanks @peter. This helped a lot. 
One more question, suppose I want to write below input in output file, how can we write it?
Input file : ['ASSSS', '2222ASS', 'AS, 33, 33', '444', '']

Output file : "ASSSS", "2222ASS", "AS, 33, 33", "444", ""]

Comment: The problem with asking follow up questions is I'm the main one who gets notified, so you're drawing on a pool of experts of size one (little old me). See if you can work it out, and if you get stuck search for a specific solution, and ask a new question if needed.

Answer (score 0):

Workaround without `csv` library, given the input string:

```
input = '"1111"","2222"2222","3333, 33, 33","444",""'
```

This is return the desired output:

```
res = input.split(",\"")
for i, e in enumerate(res):
  if len(e) > 1 and e[0] != '"' or len(e) == 1:
    res[i] = '"' + e


for e in res:
  print (e)

# "1111""
# "2222"2222"
# "3333, 33, 33"
# "444"
# ""
```

**But I don't know if it works for all the rows of the file.**